# Asp.net Gridview row edit - How to remove select row event

Tags: asp.net, select, grid, row, edit

Hi Friends wish you all Happy New Year 2017!

I am displaying records in grid and i have code to select the row and display records in text boxes as per selected row.
I have Edit Button to edit records in grid row but when i click on text box (edit mode) to enter value it is showing error because the "select row" event is still active.

Any help how to remove the select row action when edit button is clicked.

```
 // click on the row to select and display records in text boxes 
 protected void gvUsrEdit_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
 GridViewRow row = gvUsrEdit.SelectedRow;
 Label l1 = row.FindControl("Label1") as Label;
 Label l2 = row.FindControl("Label2") as Label;
 i_TranInputID.Text = l1.Text;
 tReason.Text = l11.Text;         
 gvUsrEdit.Visible = false;
 }

 protected void gvUsrEdit_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
 {
 gvUsrEdit.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
 show1(); 
 }


 public void show1()
 {
 string strquery = "select * from  btaprs2 where vEmpID=@d1 and vQuarter=@d2 and vyear1=@d3 and tKRA=@d4 and v10='Active' ";
 con.Open();
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strquery, con);
 try
 {
 SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
 DataSet ds = new DataSet();
 da.Fill(ds);
 gvUsrEdit.DataSource = ds;
 gvUsrEdit.DataBind();
 con.Close();
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
 Response.Write(ex);
 Label46.Text = "Error in page please check!";
 }
 }
```

Comment: Have a look at [this tutorial](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial/editing-data-using-asp-net-gridview-control). You don't need the `SelectedIndex` to edit rows.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `RowIndex`.

```
 protected void gvUsrEdit_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
     {
            gvUsrEdit.EditIndex = -1;
            show1(); 
     }
```

> I would suggest to `Edit` the rows this way:

You may want to use `RowUpdating` method like this:

```
    protected void gvUsrEdit_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {     
        i_TranInputID.Text = ((Label)gvUsrEdit.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("Label1") ).Text;
        tReason.Text =  ((Label)gvUsrEdit.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("Label2")).Text;
        tReason.Text = l11.Text;  
        gvUsrEdit.EditIndex = -1;       
        show1();
    }
```

Comment: Thank You  ZEZOmaster.  I will try these. i tried gvUsrEdit.EditIndex = -1; line but wasn't working....will try again both